# How to represent trans-spliced genes in GTF?

Tags: file-formats, gtf, rna-splicing

For example, see this gene (nad1) in ENA:
http://www.ebi.ac.uk/ena/data/view/ABI60879

If you look at the XML for that gene you see the following:

```
join(
             DQ984518.1: 324706 .. 325091 ,
  complement(DQ984518.1:  24417 ..  24498),
  complement(DQ984518.1:  22828 ..  23019),
             DQ984518.1:   3484 ..   3542 ,
  complement(DQ984518.1: 153702 .. 153960)
)
```

Which shows 5 exons joined out of phase and out of order. Is there a valid GTF representation of this?

How to dump a 'non-canonically spliced' gene into GTF? i.e. what's the recommendation?

Cross-posted on [biostars](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/849/how-to-represent-trans-spliced-genes-in-gtf/855#855)

Comment: Maybe you could explain better what is the particularity of splicing for this gene. It is not easy to see in the link you give.

Comment: Yes, that's much clearer. I don't have an answer, though

Answer (score 3):

To my knowledge there's no defined way to deal with that in GTF. [GFF3 handles trans-splicing](https://github.com/The-Sequence-Ontology/Specifications/blob/master/gff3.md) (you'll have to scroll down to "trans-spliced transcript") by giving an individual transcript multiple parents (e.g., `ID=some_transspliced_gene;Parent=gene1,gene2`). You could use the same methodology with GTF files, but just note that it'll break most downstream programs.

Comment: To be fair, annotating this in spec-compliant GFF3 would break the vast majority of GFF3 parsers, too. :-)